# How do I make a shortcut bash script in Termux terminal android app?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, script, android

I had to resort to using Termux since the developer of Servers Ultimate Pro has not been updating the Node.js package for a long time and the new ES6 features are breaking my scripts. After browsing instructions, I've got latest Node.js installed through apt-get and I can run my script.

However, I have to type:

```
$node storage/shared/folder_in_internal_android_memory/app.js
```

If possible could I make a bash script called "bot.sh" with:

```
#!bin/bash
node storage/shared/folder_in_internal_android_memory/app.js
```

Then run with:

```
$bot
```

I can cp an already created script but I don't know where to place it to allow me to shortcut it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using aliases?

nano/vi (or whatever you edit with) /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/bash.bashrc

Add for each alias;

alias nodeapp='node storage/shared/folder_in_internal_android_memory/app.js'

Comment: I just tested `alias s="node storage/shared/folder_in_internal_android_memory/app.js" and ran `s`. It works but it's not remembered for all sessions. Once I close Termux it forgets the command. Is it possible to set it to permanent remember it for all future sessions?

Comment: Did you just enter the alias, or did you edit the mentioned file and the alias  still didn't persist?

Comment: The node file still exist. It just forgets the alias.

Comment: That was not what I meant. Did you edit: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/bash.bashrc ?

Comment: Actually, I'm actually following this https://plus.google.com/+KanatTabaldiev/posts/RKavjA1zaCp now but I can't seem to get VIM to exit when I type :x and enter. I presume I just type `s="node storage/shared/folder_in_internal_android_memory/app.js` on one line and save.

Comment: To save and exit vim use :wq . You need to put alias in front of the s or else it will not work. You might have to restart Termux session.

Comment: It's treating the editor as text. It's not working when I enter `:wq<enter key>`. I've tried using Volume Up + E to escape but still locked in VIM.

Comment: Never mind. I've done it. Thanks for your help. I needed to Volume Up + E to trigger ESC since my keyboard doesn't have it and type :wq.

Answer (score 7):

You need to place the script in `~/.shortcuts/` and install the [Termux:Widget](https://github.com/termux/termux-widget) app. Then `Termux:Widget` options appear in your homescreen launcher's widgets list.

Per nico's comment below, to access a typical launcher's widget list, long-press an empty space and tap the option that says "widgets" or "all shortcuts". Then find and long-press the desired Termux shortcut widget and drop it where you want.

Also note that Android lacks `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, so [it is necessary to change `LD_PRELOAD`](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux) by running `pkg install termux-exec` and then restarting Termux.

Comment: I spent a long time googling to find “the usual place to add widgets to your home screen”, because I thought it was a Termux feature, when in fact it is an Android feature. For those who don’t know it yet, the solution is to press and hold on an empty space on your home screen and then tap Widgets / All shortcuts. I found the solution here: http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/mobile-devices/what-are-widgets-and-how-do-i-add-them-to-my-android-smartphone-or-tablet/

Comment: @nico Thanks for the feedback! I updated the answer to be clearer (and also updated the `/bin` and `/usr/bin` workaround while I was at it).

Answer (score 1):

[Mark's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1272919/116485) got me on the right trail which is probably beyond the scope of what the OP asked for but I guess this might help other looking for some more automated solution:

The [Termux:Task](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux:Task) *(com.termux.tasker)* app allows to integrate execution of scripts into custom flows for [tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (and compatible, like [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate)) programs.

Note that scripts to be executed need to be put to ~/.termux/tasker/ (folder also needs to be created).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to run a command or root script via termux at boot on Android and bypass security settings for super user access.. If there was some way to access Android keychain and certificates and manipulate them when they run at boot with a script then you could possibly get root access but I am not sure how to code it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1099615)